Is it possible to invert a power series with a constant term and non positive powers? Specifically the series for $x = (y + \pi/4)\csc(y)$
Consider the Taylor series for
\begin{align}
x &= \left(y+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)\csc(y) \\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{4y} + 1 +\dfrac{y\pi}{24} + \dfrac{y^2}{6} + \ldots
\end{align}
How can I invert this series? I know that for a series to be able to be reverted it needs to start with no constant and with positive integer powers of $y$.
Are there any methods to revert series with constant terms and non positive integer powers of $y$?

If you do not enjoy Laurent series, write
$$z=\frac 1 x=\frac{\sin (y)}{y+\frac{\pi }{4}}=\frac{4 y}{\pi }-\frac{16 y^2}{\pi ^2}-\frac{2 \left(\pi
   ^2-96\right) y^3}{3 \pi ^3}+\frac{8 \left(\pi ^2-96\right)
   y^4}{3 \pi ^4}+O\left(y^5\right)$$ and inverse as usual to get
$$y=\frac{\pi  }{4}z+\frac{\pi  }{4}z^2+\frac{\pi 
   \left(96+\pi ^2\right)}{384}  z^3+\frac{\pi  \left(24+\pi
   ^2\right)}{96}  z^4+O\left(z^5\right)$$ Now, let $z=\frac 1x$
